# react - how to add item to list multi-times one frame

Tags: reactjs, list, use-state

After I read relative to `useState` `set list`...etc article, solved part of my questions.
But one of my encounter issue scenarios doesn't resolve, that is ...

- a component provide a function to add item. (eg. `addItemData(data)`)
- another component call the add item function multi-times via for-loop. (eg. `dataList.foreach(data => addItemData(data.productItem))`)

What in my add function do:

```
...
const [list, setList] = useState([])
...
addItemData(data) {
    setList([..., data]);
}
```

The result is only the latest item is added, not all of them.
I consider that is they call `addItemData` in the same frame so that the `list` is the same one.

What can I do to correct this issue?

Comment: did you mean to use `setList([...list, data]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating state is asynchronous, this means that calling `setList()` doesn't update your state immediatly. Take a look at the following example that tries to call `setCount()` twice:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const addTwo = () => {
    setCount(count+1); // does not update count straightaway
    setCount(count+1); // when this runs, count is still 0,  it it performs setCount(0+1)
  }
  
  return <div>
    <p>{count}</p>
    <button onClick={addTwo}>Click me</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The above doesn't work for two reasons. One being that `setCount()` is asynchronous, so `count` won't be updated by the time the next `setCount()` immediately runs right after. Keep in mind that this could have been written as a for loop (like in your example) that iterates twice. The other reason why `count` doesn't update is that `count` is passed to `setCount()` by value (and not by reference), so it's impossible for setCount() to update your `count` variable (theoretically it's possible in your case as you're passing an array, but react doesn't modify the existing reference).

If you want to access the most up-to-date version of your state, then you can pass a callback function, which will provide you access with an up to date value of your state:

```
setList(currList => [...currList, data]);
```

You can see this working from the above example:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  const addTwo = () => {
    setCount(currCount => currCount+1);
    setCount(currCount => currCount+1); // grab current count value updated by previous `setCount()` and return the new value we want to set the state to
  }
  
  return <div>
    <p>{count}</p>
    <button onClick={addTwo}>Click me</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Ideally, you should avoid calling `setList()` multiple times to accumulate your state, and instead, accumulate your array of values first using something such as `.map()` and then set the state one time using your mapped array:

```js
addItemData(data) { // data is an array
  setList([...list, ...data]);
}
...
addItemData(dataList.map(({productItem}) => productItem));
```

Comment: It works for me!!  
It's my first seen the callback setting way with `useState`!!  
This way is called `deferred callback`...?

Comment: BTW, Let `addItemData` to accept array data is one of my solutions for me before too :D